# Как сделать выпадающее меню на css?

Tags: wordpress, css

Есть вот такая html структура: http://ssmaker.ru/7cdccba3.png

Сейчас же вот так:

[image]

```
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Хотелось бы сделать, чтобы при наведении было вот так:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в чем проблема? [Htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/) не открывается?

Оформляйте ваши

```
.nav ul li:hover > ul >li{ 
как: ваша;
душа: пожелает;
background: серый;
display: block (у вас он походу innerhit словил от самого меню,а там наверное inline-block);
и: т.д.;
}
```

Чтоб оформить выпадающее меню на css, надо владеть css.
Нужный селектор я вам написал, синтаксис попроще, чем в русском языке, а уж дальше потрудитесь сами. Ваш вопрос можно было бы и гуглу задать.